# Not able to invoke method from object reference

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

---

I am new to PHP oops and having problem with a code snippet below:-

I have a singleton class which return the object of EnityManager, and after having EM object when I try to invoke any method using auto-complete then it doesn't work. I know we need to tell IDE of the return type of a method to get things work, but I'm not able to figure out what to add to the annotations.

Please refer code snippet below :-

```
class EntityManagerUtil implements EntityManager {

    protected static $instance = null;

    private static $em = null;

    private function __construct() {
        // Making class singleton
    }

    private function __clone() {
        // Preventing from being clonned
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManagerUtil $instance
     */
    public static function getInstance() {

        if (! isset ( static::$instance )) {
            static::$instance = new EntityManagerUtil ();
            $doctrine = new \Doctrine ();
            static::$em = $doctrine->getEM ();
        }

        return static::$instance;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function getEntityManager() {

        return static::$em;

    }

}
```

After getting instance of EM:-

```
$emImpl =  \Service\Impl\EntityManagerUtil::getInstance();
$em = $emImpl->getEntityManager();
```

Where Doctrine is a class which holds a attribute named as $em.

What should I add to the return annotation for method named "getEntityManager" to get above code work?
Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: Is this a problem with your code working or a problem adding documentation for your IDE?

Comment: I solved this problem by adding the return type ( @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager) to method getEntityManager